# не могу разобраться как работает функция TrackMouseEvent C++

Tags: c++, winapi

Надо обработать события когда курсор находиться в клиентской части (консольное окно), нашел функцию TrackMouseEvent создал структуру TRACKMOUSEEVENT и передал по адресу. Но все равно функция всегда возвращает 0, вызывал GetLastError функция возвращает значение 1004. Не могу понять в чем ошибка. Если можно скиньте пример кода как должна работать функция TrackMouseEvent.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
    tme.cbSize = sizeof(tme);
    tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
    tme.dwFlags = WM_MOUSEHOVER;
    tme.dwHoverTime = 600000;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << TrackMouseEvent(&tme) << " " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Окно следует создавать самому, а не передавать дескриптор чужого окна. Собственно и результат работы будете получать через оконную процедуру указанного окна.

Comment: Да, только проблема в том что это должна быть просто консоль. Либо я не до конца понял ваше предложения.

Comment: Вы правильно поняли, эту функцию можно использовать только в графических приложениях, когда самостоятельно создаете окно и крутите цикл оконных сообщений. В чисто консольном приложении никаких окон нет.